# Why replacing a value in a DataFrame also replaces it in the original DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame 'Datos' with a long amount of dates in the index. I want to take a particular period of time so I define another dataframe as `AntCris=Datos.loc['2005-01-01':'2007-07-01']` and then I do some operations over 'AntCris' while replacing the result inside 'AntCris'. The code I use for those replacement do not work properly but this is not the point. Here is the code:

```
for x in AntCris.columns:
  aux=AntCris[x].dropna()
  aux2=aux.iloc[0]
  print(x)
  for y in AntCris[x].values:
    if np.isnan(y)==True:
      b=2
    else:
      a=np.log(y)-np.log(aux2)
      AntCris[x]=AntCris[x].replace([y],a)
```

Once the error stops this code running, sometimes I get AntCris modified but also Datos. How could I avoid that? I just want to do the changes on AntCris or even in a copy of 'Datos' but keeping the original as it was.

Comment: Aside from your question, your code is *very* inefficient and not how pandas is meant to be used. You can do what you want much simpler by using methods of the dataframe which will also be much faster.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I really do not have a lot of experience in programming or even in Python so I do what I know as I am supposed to have some support because this is an activity from the university, but I do not. How could I improve the efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a true copy of your dataframe, you can use the below command:

```
AntCris = Datos.copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

Slicing creates shallow copy whereas `copy method` can be used to create a deep copy.
Deep copy results in independent copy of the original dataframe.

To get deep copy of Datos, please use below command.

```
AntCris = Datos.copy()
```